# Can I Somehow increase Alexa default 8 seconds waiting time?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on Alexa developer console and I got to know that the default waiting time of Alexa is 8 seconds.
I'm using an API and it takes longer than 8 seconds to respond and Alexa throws Incomprehension error.
I have looked into progressive responses that developer console provides but, that too should be finished within 8 seconds.

Can I somehow increase this default waiting time from 8 seconds?

Comment: No, there is no way to change that. If the external API causes timeouts, you should consider some work somewhere else (caching?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Alexa timeout is 10 seconds and you cannot change this time, please follow this [Amazon developer forum thread](https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/questions/9176/what-is-the-timeout-of-the-request-sent-by-alexa.html)